# Can you help me explaining the following C code?

Tags: c, shellcode

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
   int (*func)();    
   func = (int (*)()) code;   
   (int)(*func)();    
}
```

the variable code has some shellcode in it

Comment: What part of the shown code do you have questions about? One specific line? All three lines? Please try to be more specific.

Comment: all three lines .. dont know what each of them means

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers. This code snippet should help you understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Hello();
int code();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
   int (*func)(); //pointer to function that takes no arguments quivalent to: int (*func)(void);
   func =&Hello;
   int x = func();
   printf("%d\n", x);

    func = (int (*)()) code; // Assigns the pointer from the code function to the func pointer
    x = code();
    printf("%d", x);
}
int code()
{
    printf("code returns: ");
    return 500;
}

int Hello()
{
    printf("hello returns: ");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`code` probably is a variable that correspond to the address of some machine code in memory. Then a pointer to function that takes no parameter and returns an int is set to that address and the function is called. `int f()` is the prototype for a function with no param and int as return value, then `int (*pf)()` is a pointer to such a function.

Comment: "_takes no parameter_" - Actually, it should be "takes an unspecified number of arguments"

Comment: Right, was using c++ rule...